# How to add view components dynamically from activity

Tags: android, android-canvas

I am attempting to create a user interface dynamically. I have successfully create a view and loaded my background image. I have created two additional small view items to display on the background. My problem is that I have not been able to find any advice/instruction that tells me how to draw the small views. It seems that it should be a trivial exercise and I am guessing it is just finding the correct referencing. Hope someone out there can point me in the right direction.

Here is my Activity:

```
public class GhostActivity extends Activity implements OnTouchListener
{
private DrawView ghostView;
public Card mCard1, mCard2;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // ToDo add your GUI initialization code here        
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // requesting to turn the title OFF
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    // making it full screen
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,  WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    ghostView = new DrawView(this);
    setContentView(ghostView);

    //get the window size
    Display display = ((WindowManager) getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE)).getDefaultDisplay();

    Context context = getApplicationContext();
    //create view items with initial positions
    Point startPoint;
    startPoint = new Point();
    startPoint.x = 5;
    startPoint.y = 3;
    mCard1 = new Card(context, 1, R.drawable.bol_geel, startPoint);
    startPoint.x = 5;
    startPoint.y = 43;
    mCard2 = new Card(context, 2, R.drawable.bol_rood, startPoint);

    //now display them on the ghostView *****************HOW?

    // set the callbacks
    ghostView.setOnTouchListener(this);
    mCard1.setOnTouchListener(this);
    mCard2.setOnTouchListener(this);

    }
```

and here is the View;

```
public class DrawView extends View 
{
Drawable bg ; 
public DrawView(Context context) {
   super(context);
   //setFocusable(true); 
   Drawable bg = this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.bubbleblue480x800);
   setBackgroundDrawable(bg);
   }


@Override protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
//   canvas.drawColor(0x0000000);     //if you want another background color       

    //draw  on the canvas
  }
}
```

edit: I believe my problem is needing to pass a pointer to the ghostView canvas. what makes me think that is if I create the children within ghostView then call their .draw method they appear exactly as I would expect.

```
@Override protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    canvas.drawColor(0x0000000);     //if you want another background color       

    //draw the cards on the canvas
    mCard1.draw(canvas);
    mCard2.draw(canvas);
}
```

so at this point I am wondering how to get a reference pointer to the ghostView canvas.
To be honest I am finding the whole Activity - View relationship confusing.

Edit: I have taken a different approach based on detail in this tutorial
http://www.kellbot.com/2009/06/android-hello-circle/
It uses a FrameLayout and it seems I can achieve my objective.

Answer (score 0):

To add view dynamically to view your class must extends from ViewGroup or LinearLayout class then you will able to call method addView.

Comment: Thanks s_id, I will research ViewGroup further.

Answer (score 0):

Inside your ghost view first add a layout e.g Linear or Relative. Then only you could able to add views inside that layout you cant simply add a view to a xml file.

Or you can create a dynamic layout then only u can add view inside that layout.

```
RelativeLayout relative= new RelativeLayout(findViewById(R.id.your relativeLayoutID));
    relative.addView(child);
```

child could be anything button textview and widget.

Comment: Thanks but I am specifically trying to avoid the restrictions of the defined layouts. The only one I would use (absolute) is deprecated.